# expected integer but got "match_max" in statement match_max -d 1000000000 -i $chassis_spwan_id

Tags: tcl, expect

I am getting below error on this line of my code ,we have linux upgrade recently ,it seems there is some change happen in TCl or EXPECT package ,earlier this code use to work in my scripts-

### Code-

```
match_max -d 1000000000 -i $chassis_spwan_id
```

### Error

```
expected integer but got "match_max" in statement match_max -d 1000000000 -i $chassis_spwan_id
```

I notice that in place of `match_max -d 1000000000 -i $chassis_spwan_id` if I give only `match_max -d 1000000000` then it works.

Please let me know if anybody is aware of this issue.

My TCL is 8.5 and expect is 5.44.1.15 and my rhel is 6.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match_max` should be used like this:

```
# get current buffer size
match_max [−i spawn_id]

# set to the default size (2000 bytes)
match_max −d [−i spawn_id]

# set to the specified size
match_max [−i spawn_id] size
```

Your `match_max -d 1000000000` did not really work as you expected. Actually the value `1000000000` is ignored.

Comment: thanks whjm,i tried like this but it didn't work - match_max [-i $chassis_spwan_id] 1000000000

Comment: the `[ ]` here means this part is optional.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need put 1000000000 in the end of command. First come flags, then parameters.

`match_max -i $chassis_spwan_id 1000000000`

2. I think you cannot use -d and -i in same time.

Comment: the error is the same as I posted in the original question.

Comment: May be your digit to big for integer. If your system 32bit, try 2147483648, or less